# Create a grouped bar chart of sums in plotly

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have the dataframe below :

```
agegroup<-c("0-4","0-4","5-15","5-15")
gender<-c("Male","Female","Male","Female")
week<-c("a","b","c","d")
cases<-c(20,40,35,67)
df<-data.frame(agegroup,gender,week,cases)
```

and I want to create a grouped bar chart by cases and gender with the relative hovertemplate like:

[image]

my code :

```
fig <- plot_ly(df, x = ~agegroup, y = ~cases, type = 'bar', name = 'Male',hovertemplate = paste('%{x}', '<br>cases: %{y}<br><extra></extra>'), marker = list(color = '#6bbabf'))
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~cases, name = 'Female',hovertemplate = paste('%{x}', '<br>cases: %{y}<br><extra></extra>'), marker = list(color = '#60ab3d'))
fig <- fig %>% layout(barmode = 'group')
fig
fig
```

my issues are that I cannot display the total sum per age group and every bar is like is cut into pieces and I cannot display the `gender` in my hovertext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following:

```
library(plotly)
library(data.table)

agegroup <- c("0-4", "0-4", "5-15", "5-15")
gender <- c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Female")
week <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
cases <- c(20, 40, 35, 67)
df <- data.frame(agegroup, gender, week, cases)
setDT(df)
df[, agegroupsum := sum(cases), by = agegroup]
# setDF(df)

fig <- plot_ly(
    data = df,
    x = ~ agegroup,
    y = ~ cases,
    type = 'bar',
    color = ~ gender,
    colors = c('#6bbabf', '#60ab3d'),
    text = ~ paste("<b>Gender:</b>", gender, "<br><b>Age:</b>", agegroup, "<br><b>Cases:</b>", cases, "<br><b>Total cases in age group:</b>", agegroupsum),
    hovertemplate = paste('%{text}<extra></extra>')
  ) %>% layout(barmode = 'group')

fig
```

[image: result]